# Probability Questions about the set "A given B"

Tags: probability

Is the following true for the set A, if A and B are joint events?

$$ \text{A} = (A|B)\cup{(A|B^c)} $$

And since $(A|B)$ is disjoint from $(A|B^c)$ can we use the axiom of probability to state:

$$P(A) = P(A|B) + P(A|B^c)$$

Cause I know that $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ so when adding the two I get confused and it seems like it is not true.

Any insight into this question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\mid B$ is not a set. However, it is true that
$$ A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c) $$
with the sets on the right being disjoint, hence
$$ \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c) $$
Using the definition of conditional probability, we can rewrite this as
$$ \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)\mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{P}(A\mid B^c)\mathbb{P}(B^c)$$
provided that $\mathbb{P}(B),\mathbb{P}(B^c)>0$.

This last formula can also be extended to the case when one of $\mathbb{P}(B),\mathbb{P}(B^c)$ is zero by setting the corresponding term to be zero, even though the conditional probability is not defined.